# Morphism from a line bundle to a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be flat family of Projective varieties.

Let $L$ be an invertible sheaf and $E$ a locally free sheaf on $X$.

1) Any non-zero morphism $L\rightarrow E$ is injective. Is this right? Because this morphism gives a morphism $O_X\rightarrow E\otimes L^{-1}$, and such a morphism is given by a section and hence is injective.

2) Suppose $g: L\rightarrow E$ is an injective morphism. Then for any $y\in Y$, consider the morphism of fibres $g_y:L_y\rightarrow E_y$. By part (1) this should be injective or zero. But we started with $g$ injective. So this will imply that the induced morphism is injective right? Can it be the zero morphism?

Comment: Just a comment on injectivity : there are two different notions here. Injectivity as a morphism of sheaves and injectivity as a morphism of vector bundles. An injective morphism of sheaves $L\rightarrow E$ is often non injective as a morphism of vector bundle, see for example Hanno's counter-example.

Comment: @Roland, a morphism of vector bundles which happens to be a monomorphism in the category of coherent sheaves is also a monomorphism in the category of vector bundles, but the quotient coherent sheaf need not be a vector bundle - do you mean that?

Comment: @Hanno Sorry for my late answer. I meant a morphism $L\rightarrow E$ making $L$ a subbundle of $E$, or equivalently such that $L\rightarrow E$ is fiberwise injective. It is indeed equivalent to the requirement that the quotient sheaf is a vector bundle. But you are right that this does not correspond to the categorical meaning of monomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*No, some fibers can vanish.* Look at the case where $X=Y$ and $L={\mathcal O}_X$. Then, as you already said, $L\to E$ is given by a global section $s$ of $E$, and $g_y$ is zero precisely if $s$ vanishes at $y$. E.g., you could take $X=Y={\mathbb P}^1$, $E = {\mathcal O}(1)$, and $s:=x\in \Gamma({\mathcal O}(1))\cong k[x,y]_1$. Then $g_p$ vanishes for $p := (0:1)$.

Comment: thanks! Since such a morphism is given by a global section, some fibres will always vanish?

Comment: what about the specific case when $f$ has positive dimensional isomorphic fibres. In some sense $X$ is a constant family of varieties.

Comment: @gradstudent That doesn't help, take the examole at add an arbitrary factor to $Y $

Comment: sorry I don't understand your comment.. What is adding an arbitrary factor to $Y$ mean

Comment: @gradstudent Sorry, it was a bit sloppy, I was still in bed ;) I mean that you take $Y = {\mathbb P}_1\times Z$ projecting onto $X = {\mathbb P}_1$, and $L := {\mathcal O}_Y$, $L = p^{\ast}({\mathcal O}(1))$ and $s := p^{\ast}(x)$. So, basically the same example as above, but with an arbitrary factor added to $Y$.

Comment: oh awesome. Out of curiosity, here the line bundle comes from below. Is that some necessary condition? Because if we have a line bundle below, it's vanishing gives rise to an entire fibre vanishing.

Comment: @gradstudent Hm, I'm not an expert, but it might be that in some special situations, the property does hold. For example, naively it seems conceivable to me that there could be an example of $f$ where $Y$ is a curve and the flat pullback $f^{\ast}: \text{Cl}^1(Y)\to\text{Cl}^1(X)$ is not surjective. If you pick $E$ a degree $1$ line bundle such that its divisor class does not belong to the image of $f^{\ast}$, then no global section of $E$ could vanish on a fiber of $f$ (as otherwise that fiber would be a representative of the divisor class of $E$). But maybe such an example does not exist...

Comment: sounds interesting! Thank you. Things are clear now.

Comment: @gradstudent Great, could you accept then?

Comment: I am really sorry! I thought I had accepted the answer right away. I just realised I hadn't. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For a vector bundle morphism $f:E\rightarrow F$, it induces the sheaf morphism $\widetilde f:\mathcal O(E)\rightarrow \mathcal O(F)$, the following example illustrates that sometimes, it may occurs $\widetilde f$ being injective while $f$ not.

Consider two $1$-trivial vector bundles $E$, $E^\prime$ on $\mathbb C$, and define $f$ by $$f: E\rightarrow E^\prime,\,\,(x,v)\mapsto(x,g(x)v).$$
Here $g(x)\in\mathcal O(\mathbb C),g\not=0,g(0)=0.$
Then $f$ is not injective, while $\widetilde f$ is.