# Morphism from a line bundle to a vector bundle -2

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is closely related to the following question.

[Morphism from a line bundle to a vector bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212025/morphism-from-a-line-bundle-to-a-vector-bundle)

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are smooth irreducible projective varieties. In fact $Y$ is a homogeneous space. Consider the projection $p:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$. Then for each $y\in Y$, the fibre over $y$ is $X$.

Consider an invertible sheaf $L$ and a locally free sheaf $E$  on $X\times Y$. Then $L$ and $E$ give constant family of invertible sheaves and locally free sheaves on $X$ as $y$ varies over $Y$.

Suppose $f:L\rightarrow E$ is a non-zero morphism. Then it is injective. Then consider the fibres over $y\in Y$ i.e. $f_y:L_y\rightarrow E_y$, a morphism from an invertible    sheaf to a locally free sheaf on $\{y\}\times X$. Suppose I know that for some $y$ this is injective, then for all $y$ this is injective right?

And this has to be injective for some $y$. For otherwise for all $y\in Y$ this morphism is zero. This contradicts injectivity of $f$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, this is not true. Consider $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$ with the map $\mathcal{O}\to\mathcal{O}$ (pullled back from the projective line), multiplication by $t$, the parameter of the affine line. It is zero over $t=0$, but injective elsewhere.